# Pulling data from a web-hosted CSV in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, crash, timeout

I am automating a data pull process.

Excel will crash on a `.PasteSpecial` line.

Here is an example:

```
'Pull Data
httpRequest.Open "GET", urlstring, False
httpRequest.send ""
tableStr = httpRequest.responseText

DataObj.SetText tableStr
DataObj.PutInClipboard

'paste data
Worksheets("NSData").Select
Range("B" & lastrows).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial
```

This works when running a single process as a test, but with 20-30 processes it begins to crash here.

I am wondering if there is a better way to write this, but the main problem is I am unsure how to copy data from the CSV and paste it into my workbook; specifically `DataObj.PutInClipboard` - is there an alternative?

Comment: Try `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(urlstring)` to open the data directly in Excel.